# Cauchy's Theorem, Stokes' Theorem, de Rham Cohomology

Tags: complex-analysis, de-rham-cohomology

I've been struggling these last couple of days to see the connection, if at all there is one, between the following facts:

1. For holomorphic functions $f$, $\mathrm{d}(f(z)\mathrm{d}z) = 0$.
2. In a simply connected domain, a holomorphic function has a primitive, i.e. there exists a function $g$ defined over this domain such that $g'=f$.
3. The de Rham Cohomology "measures the failure of closed forms to be exact".

Trying to convince myself that Cauchy's theorem is somehow geometrically intuitive led me to the one-line proof where point 1 above is combined with Stoke's theorem, which in turn has led me to wonder if there was something going on at the level of differential forms over $\mathbb{C}$. I apologise if the question is unclear; as I said, I have the feeling like there's a revelation about holomorphic functions dancing just out of my reach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are easy and hard things to see here. Let me see if I can help.

**Complex valued differential forms** First of all, throughout this answer, I'll want to work with differential forms that take complex values. So a differential $k$-form, at each point of $\mathbb{C}$, will take as input $k$ tangent vectors and output a complex number. The formalism is exactly the same as the real-valued case. So, if $z=x+iy$, we literally have the equation $dz = dx + i dy$, meaning that if $z$ is the coordinate function on $\mathbb{C}$, with $x$ the real part of $z$ and $y$ the imaginary part of $z$, then $dz$, $dx$ and $dy$ are one forms which obey the relation $dz=dx+i dy$.

For any **smooth** function $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, we have $df = \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz + \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} d\overline{z}$, where
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right) \ \mbox{and} \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right).$$

The Cauchy-Riemann equations tell us that $f$ is **holomorphic** if and only if $\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} + i \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$, so $f$ is holomorphic if and only if $\overline{\partial}(f)=0$. In that case, $df = \partial f$.

If $g$ is holomorphic, then $d \left( g\ dz \right) = dg \wedge dz = g'(z) dz \wedge dz = 0$.

**So, what does this mean for de Rham cohomology of open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$?**  Let $g(z)$ be holomorphic. From the last paragraph above, $g dz$ is closed. By de Rham's theorem, $g dz$ will be exact if and only if $\oint_{\gamma} g=0$ for every closed path $\gamma$.

Now, all that de Rham's theorem gives us is that $g dz = df$ for some **smooth** function $f$. But then we have $g dz = \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} dz + \tfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} d \overline{z}$ so, comparing coefficients of $d \overline{z}$ on both sides, $\tfrac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} =0$ and $f$ will actually be **holomorphic**.

So just using de Rham's theorem for (complex valued) $1$-forms, and good notation, immediately tells us the statement for holomorphic functions.

**A much harder issue** A much harder and more interesting question is whether the holomorphic analogue of the de Rham complex will compute cohomology. For some open region $U$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$, let $\Omega^p$ be the $p$-forms of the form $\sum g_{i_1 i_2 \cdots i_p}(z_1, \ldots, z_n) dz_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge dz_{i_p}$, with $g_{i_1 \cdots i_p}$ holomorphic functions. Take the cohomology of the complex $0 \to \Omega^0 \to \Omega^1 \to \cdots \to \Omega^n \to 0$. There is always a map from this cohomology to de Rham, because every class is represented by a closed form, and we can consider that form as a de Rham class. But will that map be an isomorphism?  (In the first draft, I called this Dolbeault cohomology, but that's something else. No deep reason for the error, I just wasn't thinking.)

In general, the answer is **no**! For example, $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ (0,0) \}$ retracts onto the $3$-sphere, so it has nontrivial $H^3$, but the holomorphic complex only goes up to degree $2$. 
There is also a more subtle possible issue -- there are complex $3$-folds with holomorphic $3$-forms which are exact but are not the differential of a holomorphic $2$-form; see Cordero, Fernandez and Gray "The Frölicher spectral sequence and complex compact nilmanifolds".

But for open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, the answer is yes! In general, the answer is yes for [Stein spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein_manifold). If you are looking for motivation to get into the sort of harder multivariable complex analysis where the Stein condition comes up, this is a great starting point.

Comment: Thanks David! You've given me plenty to think about.